# Is it bad/distracting to place long action tags between dialogue?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

Two examples to illustrate:

> “It wasn’t suddenly.” Aru sipped her Americano. She bought it because
>   it cost ¥499, and she loved prime numbers. They were unique.
>   Unbreakable. “Have you seen the movie Pretty Woman?”
>
> “Let me get this straight.” Ichi was the guy who had recently joined
>   Aru’s car dealership. Also the guy who had recently confessed his love
>   to her. “You suddenly decided to quit your job as an accountant—to
>   pursue a career as a sex worker?”

Will the be distracting for the reader? What to do in cases like this? Put the action tags at the beginning of the dialogue? At the end?

Comment: I would put it after that line, but I don't have a specific reason, it just seems more right, and I have no idea what the policy on answering here is, so...

Comment: The only drawback to the tags you have here is that the length of them creates a pause in the reader's mind between the two pieces of dialogue. If you intend for the person to be speaking continuously, without a few seconds between each sentence, then shorten your tags.

Comment: Long time no see, Alexandro. How's your novel coming along? I like the examples. I agree with Lauren (the inserts create a pause). I disagree with Daniel (the telling is fine here and fits the humorous style).

Comment: @what Yeah, long time. The novel got good reviews http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27430688-animal-suicide. Thanks for the feedback you gave me back then.

Comment: Now that's great! So good luck with your next project :-) Glad you keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It Depends

> Will it be distracting for the reader?

Firstly, I can't not comment on the following: there are immense amounts of telling in this piece. I feel that the sense of 'bad' writing being created here isn't actually formed by the action tags, rather the telling.

> She bought it because it cost ¥499, and she loved prime numbers.

That specifically, and all of your other action tags are telling me things. Each one **tells** me information that could be **shown** in a more interesting way. It seems boring and bad because you're just telling me the information in such a plain form. I won't write for you, instead I'll give you the golden advice:

- Show. Don't tell.

I'll actually give a *very* primitive example of what showing could be like for the above quote:

> Aru beamed at the price tag: ¥499. A prime number.

It's obvious that she beams at the price tag because of the prime number. Rather than telling the reader that she loves prime numbers, you're showing them.

### The Action Tags

To be entirely honest, I think you can leave them where they are in the sentence. However, perhaps you could add some indication as to how they are speaking. Here's a thought:

> “It wasn’t suddenly,” Aru spluttered outwards through a sip of her Americano.

I think it would be good to do something like this because it helps more easily lead into the action tags. In your work it felt a little abrupt. It is almost as if something is going on, and then a fatal error has occurred and you have randomly decided to give me information. It doesn't flow, and I think this could help it flow more easily.

I hope this helped.